# How to access form value in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

```
<form name="vm.form">
 <input name="name">
 <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

How can I access input value with vm.form?

I've tried this, but it's not working:
`console.log(vm.form.name)`

Can I do it like this? Or are there any other easy way?

I'm posting data to other server like this:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', vm.form, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: How is not working? It's not printing it? It's showing an error? Also, which browser are you using? Console.log doesn't work on IE <9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object in your controller

```
$scope.form = {name:"", password=""}
```

and then you can access it in your html via the `ng-model`

```
<form>
<input ng-model="form.name">
<input type="password" ng-model="form.password">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `var` in `var $scope.form = ...`

Comment: You are right. I was not sure about this but now i changed it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: 
in your HTML

```
<form name="vm.form" ng-model="myForm">
 <input name="name" ng-model="myForm.name">
 <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="myForm.password">
</form>
```

and in your script use "myForm"

```
$http.post('/someUrl', $scope.myForm, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<form name="vm.form" ng-submit="YourServerSideFun(myForm)">
<input name="name" ng-model="myForm.name">
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="myForm.password">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Pass your myForm as Object.